# Java - Can't access a class from the name alone

Tags: java, oop

First off I'm quite new to java.  I'm trying to manipulate my code as much as I can to get a good understanding of it.  The following code works perfectly, but when I try to move it into it's own construct (i think that's the right term) it fails.  Also, the code is just of a small relevant portion.

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    Hero Player1 = new Hero();
    Hero Player2 = new Hero();
    Player2.takeDamage(Player1.giveDamage());
    Player1.takeDamage(Player2.giveDamage());
}

// Fails if:
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    Hero Player1 = new Hero();
    Hero Player2 = new Hero();
    combatPhase();
}

private static void combatPhase() {
    Player2.takeDamage(Player1.giveDamage());
    Player1.takeDamage(Player2.giveDamage());
}
```

Basically it wants me to use Hero.takeDamage instead of Player1/2.  Is there a fairly easy way to fix this so I can put it in combatPhase() to keep my code more organized?

Comment: Can you show the takeDamage() method and any other relevant info in the Hero class?

Comment: Note you should use conventional camelCasing for variables; `Hero player1` and `Hero player2` (note lack of 'player' capitalization).

Comment: What do you mean with "it fails", can you be more precise?

Comment: giveDamage and takeDamage both work fine.  The problem is only when I try to create combatPhase() outside of main().  It's identical code in both, but it does not let me refer to Player1/2 in combatPhase().

Comment: For us to answer, you need to provide a lot more. Are these functions all in the same class? What error are you actually getting? Is it a 'you can't call a static method' error? (Do you know the difference between static and non static classes?)

Comment: no it's telling me Player1/2 cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options you have, the first is to pass the Heroes into the combatPhase method like this:

```
    public static void main(Strings[] args)
    {
      Class main = new Class();
      Hero player1 = new Hero();
      Hero player2 = new Hero();
      main.combatPhase(player1, player2);
    }

    private void combatPhase(Hero player1, Hero player2){
      player2.takeDamage(player1.giveDamage());
      player1.takeDamage(player2.giveDamage());
    }
```

or you could declare the Heroes first like this:

```
    Hero player1 = new Hero();
    Hero player2 = new Hero();

    public static void main(Strings[] args)
    {
      Class main = new Class();
      main.combatPhase();
    }

    private void combatPhase(){
      player2.takeDamage(player1.giveDamage());
      player1.takeDamage(player2.giveDamage());
    }
```

Comment: `player1` and `player2` need to be defined as static in the second example as well as `combatPhase()` (in both versions) or you create a new instance of the class that is hosting the code

Comment: Yes Roman your correct, I would use `Class main = new Class();` and then call `main.combatPhase();`.

Answer (score 0):

I could be long to explain everything in detail, cause I'm not sure what's the exact part you don't understand.

I think a good code could be preferable. This is not THE way to go but it's a good one.

First let's define a hero:

```
public class Hero {
    private int damage;

    public Hero(int damage){
        this.damage = damage;
    }
    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }
    public void takeDamage(int damage){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Now a basic fight as main:

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    Hero player1 = new Hero();
    Hero player2 = new Hero();
    player2.takeDamage(player1.getDamage());
    player1.takeDamage(player2.getDamage());
}
```

Comment: `getDamage()` is a bit misleading in that specific case ;) I'd call it `dealDamage()`

Comment: essentially that's what it is.  I'm trying to manipulate the second part of it to put the bottom half of the code into another public static void combatPhase() outside of main().